# Find format of data from Steam API using Python

Tags: python, steam

I have some user data downloaded using the Steam API (I am following the approach described [here](https://github.com/vh42720/csgo_cheater_detection)) and I need to find the format for each entry of the CSV file I generated (available [here](https://gist.github.com/albusdemens/22c81fe6c06bde0421c94fa86cefffcf)).

Using Python, the solution I came up with is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

df1 = pd.read_csv("./data/csgo_cheater_data_01_14_21_full.csv")
for ii in range(189):
    print(df1.columns[ii], type(df1[df1.columns[ii]].values[0]))
```

Running this snipped, the result is that most variables are float64, plus a few int64. Does it make sense? Is this the *real* format of the data or are they somehow converted when retrieved using the API?

Comment: Since you can open csv in any text editor and the first line give you somelike total_of_x, numeric values do make sense

Comment: Have you found any specific variables that don't look like they make sense in the format your code reads them currently? A concrete example can help focus answers. Or, if all the variables make sense to you in their current format, then what is the problem to solve?